# Regular expression to allow either number or special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex to allow characters, atleast one number and special character text limit 8 to 15..

```
function validatePassword(password) {
    var re = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@.$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@.$!%*#?&]{8,15}$/i;
    return re.test(password);
}
```

Now I need to change this regex to accept either one number or one special character and same 8 to 15 limit

Comment: Do you mean it must require exactly one number *or* special character (but not both), with the other characters being all alphabetic?

Comment: show some examples of valid/invalid inputs. It's not clear from your description whether it should consider other alpha characters or it shouldn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the lookahead requiring a digit, and move the `\d` to the lookahead requiring a special character:

```
var re = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[\d$@.!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@.!%*#?&]{8,15}$/;
                               ^^
```

If you do not need to require at least one letter, remove `(?=.*[A-Za-z])`.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*[A-Za-z])` - there must be at least 1 ASCII letter
- `(?=.*[\d$@.$!%*#?&])` - there must be at least 1 digit, or any one of the special chars in the class
- `[A-Za-z\d$@.!%*#?&]{8,15}` - the string should only consist of letters, digits, and the special chars listed, from 8 to 15 occurrences.
- `$`  - end of string.

Note that once you are using `a-zA-Z`, you do not need the `/i` case insensitive modifier.

Also, no ned to repeat `$` in one and the same character class.

Comment: BTW, you may test the regex [here, at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tB4mL6/1).

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to unify the digits and the special character lookaheads:

```
function validatePassword(password) {
    var re = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[$@.$!%*#?&0-9])[A-Za-z\d$@.$!%*#?&]{8,15}$/i;
    return re.test(password);
}
```

Explanation:

- digits can be specified as `[0-9]` or as `\d` too.
- I chose the character class specification so they fit into the special character char class.
- A lookahead is something like `(?=...)`